# how to get input value on button click in stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

could you please tell me how to get input value on button click in stateless component .I want to pass input value in `container component`
I tried like this .here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/l9j42k5q49

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const TabbarComponent = props => {
  const onInputChange = event => {};
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={() => props.addEventHandler()}>Add Items</button>
    </div>
  );
};

TabbarComponent.propTypes = {
  addEventHandler: PropTypes.func
};

export default TabbarComponent;
```

here I want input value in this function

```
addButtonClickHandler(val) {
    alert("ddd");
    let names = this.state.names.slice();
    names.push(val);
    this.setState({
      names: names
    });
  }
```

`val` is `input field value` whatever user enter in input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to give `onClick` a fat arrow function. Just give it the reference to the `addButtonClickHandler`, like this:

```
<button onClick={props.addEventHandler}>Add Items</button>
```

You *can* do a fat arrow function if you want (not recommended), but in that case you need to pass the event too:

```
<button onClick={(e) => props.addEventHandler(e)}>Add Items</button>
```

Comment: i want input field value also

Comment: @user944513 that's a bit problematic the way you've done it. Your input is currently an "uncontrolled input", which means that you have to get the value via the DOM, rather than from React. Since `ref` don't work in functional components, your only option is using something like `document.getElementById`, which is not recommended. I would convert that component to a stateful component and make your input controlled.

Comment: so you are trying to say I will change this component to stateful and set the state ?

Comment: can you change my `codesandbox` link ..provide me update code